# Interval not clearing after navigation away

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

After I navigate to a new page in my react web app, I've noticed it continues to log fetch requests against my api. I've tried adding a bit to clear it in the way component unmount worked on Class components, but its still logging at set intervals.

Can someone advise me please.

I've tried looking at other questions and what I've tried seems to be the answer, but it isn't working.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);

      try {
        const res = await fetch(`http://xxxx`, {
          method: "POST",
          mode: "cors",
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            credentials: "include"
          }
        });
        res.json().then(res => setApiResponse(res));
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }

      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();

    setInterval(fetchData, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(fetchData);
  }, []);
```

I want it to clear the interval and stop the 'leak'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clearInterval` expects a reference to an interval function (returned by `setInterval`), not the function you're calling it from:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let interval;

    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsError(false);

      try {
        const res = await fetch(`http://xxxx`, {
          method: "POST",
          mode: "cors",
          headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            credentials: "include"
          }
        });
        res.json().then(res => setApiResponse(res));
      } catch (error) {
        setIsError(true);
      }

      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();

    interval = setInterval(fetchData, 3000); // save the id if the interval
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);
```